throw new Error(`A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of '${this.tableName}' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true'`);
i have an error with this table but ia already migrate with fluently, whats wrong with this? anyone can help?
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('categories', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },

Error: A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'categories' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true'
in another case i success to migrate this table to my db
== 20240513171509-create-category: migrating =======
== 20240513171509-create-category: migrated (0.082s)

Please indicate where you get this error exactly
